# how to get user object and pass it to form field in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

is there a better way to get the user object from the code below in `forms.py`?

## models

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

## forms.py

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("user")
        super(ExperienceStart, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(InlineRadios('topics'),)

    hardcoded_username = "johndoe" # i want to find a way not to hardcode this

    current_user = User.objects.filter(username=hardcoded_username).first()

    profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=current_user).first()

    ...

    profile_values = list(zip(profile, profile))

    profile = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        label="Select a Profile",
        choices=profile_values,
        coerce=str,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        initial=profile[0],
        required=True)
```

## views.py

```
def foo(request):
    form = fooForm(request.POST, user=request.user)

    print(form.request) # i have already tried this but i want to get it in form not views

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            # do something
    else:
        form = fooForm(user=request.user)

    context = {"form": form}
```

I am trying to find a way not to hardcode the username in `forms.py` and get the current logged in user.

Comment: Why include it in the form, and not just use the user in the `# do something`. A Django form is used to validate and clean HTML input, not to handle the logged in user.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thats a good point. what i want to accomplish is create a form that render some radio buttons from a field in `Profile` table above, i dont think there is a way to handle radio button in the views only

Comment: But your `profile_values = list(zip(profile, profile))` only seems to deal with a *single* `Profile` object, so it seems there are no choices? There is only one choice?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem multiple choices but the user can only select one answer, the line you just pasted is not a problem, it work fine. the only thing that i am trying to accomplish is what i mentioned above, i dont think there is a way to handle a multiple choice radio button form in django without using form.py as long as using  `django monolithic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't** include it in the form. Forms are typically *request unaware*, and furthermore are used to process input from the HTML form.

You can make use of the `initial=…` parameter of the form to specify the initial item.

In your form you can use a [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) to select a `Profile` item:

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):

    profile = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label='Select a Profile',
        queryset=Profile.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        required=True
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(InlineRadios('topics'))
```

then in the view, you can pass the profile of the user as initial value:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def foo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = fooForm(request.POST, initial={'profile': request.user.profile})
        if form.is_valid():
            # do something
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = fooForm(initial={'profile': request.user.profile})
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.